# start a ros node executable in a launch file without a workspace

Tags: ubuntu, ros, launch

i have compiled ros nodes and would like to start thoose in a launch file wihtout a workspace.

I could write a scrip with code like:

```
./path_to_node/node_name _param1:="bla" _param2:="blu"
./path_to_node2/node_name2 _param1:="bla2" _param2:="blu2"
```

but i would prefer using a launch file and to something like (pseudo code):

```
<arg name="odometry_frame_id" default="/odom"/>
<node if="$(arg start_detection)"  type="/path2noe/std_filter_node" name="std_filter_node" output="screen" >
    <param name="base_link_height" type="double" value="0.0"/>
    <param name="input_frame" type="str" value="$(arg detection_frame_id)"/>
    <param name="odom_frame_id" type="str" value="$(arg odometry_frame_id)"/>
 </node>
```

is something like this possible?

Comment: It is technically possible, but the solutions aren't great. Why exactly do you want to launch without a workspace? Because there is most likely a better solution depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have several systems to which I would like to transfer only the binaries

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't a *nice* way to run raw executables via `roslaunch` for a couple of different reasons.

Since you're wanting to run these nodes on another machine that doesn't include the workspace, your best bet is to install them in `/opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/`. This will allow you to write normal launch files.

If the second machine temporarily has the workspace you can follow [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_a_workspace). If you want to be able to simply install and run the nodes without creating a local workspace, you should [make a debian package](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=910717). With this option you should copy files from your local workspace to be installed in the `lib` and `share` folders of `/opt/ros/` of the secondary machine. For example:

```
cd ~/catkin_ws/
mkdir DEBIAN_BUILD_DIR
mkdir -p DEBIAN_BUILD_DIR/opt/ros/noetic/share
mkdir -p DEBIAN_BUILD_DIR/opt/ros/noetic/lib
cp -r devel/share DEBIAN_BUILD_DIR/opt/ros/noetic/share
cp -r devel/lib DEBIAN_BUILD_DIR/opt/ros/noetic/lib
```

Once you've created the package you can simply install it on the other machine via `sudo dpkg -i <package_name>`